# Get value off querystring by it's position

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a URL that's going to have one parameter on it but the 'name' of this parameter will, in some cases, be different eg.

www.mysite.com/blog/?name=craig

www.mysite.com/blog/?city=birmingham

and what I'm trying to do is always get the value (craig / birmingham) of the first (and only) parameter on the string regardless of it's name (name/ city). Is there any code that will do that or will I have to check the possible options?

thanks,
Craig

Comment: I don't think there is class that guarantees indexes of query parameters to stay the same... I'd cut name from query string (up to first `=`) and than use regular methods to grab query paramter from the url.

Comment: A couple questions before I answer: If the URL is www.mysite.com/blog/?name=craig&city=birmingham, does that mean you have the parameter called "name" with value "craig"? Or are you only gonna use this internally, so that you're certain there will always be one parameter? Can the parameter name be anything?

Comment: You could target the URI (string), split the string at the first occurrence of `=` to retrieve the name. However, it may be better to set up an object and place it in a session if it makes sense.

Comment: This is really dangerous since I can fill in a querystring with a bunch of fake param combinations before the actual data and the server will ignore them.  So you're creating a very painful headache if you do it this way.

Comment: The parameter name could be anything and yes it's for an internal system. I'm just trying to get the first parameter vale and display it back to the user (it's a long story!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
string valueOfFirstQueryStringParameter = "";
string nameOfFirstQueryStringParameter = "";
NameValueCollection n = Request.QueryString;
if (n.HasKeys())
{
    nameOfFirstQueryStringParameter = n.GetKey(0);
    valueOfFirstQueryStringParameter = n.Get(0);
}
```

Comment: That just yields the value of the first query string parameter, the OP wants name and value.

Comment: Code edited to include retrieving querystring parameter name, BUT the way  I read the OP, this NOT required.

Comment: I stand corrected. The question is a little ambiguous, but I think you are correct, he only wanted the value.

Comment: Yip, I just need the value and that works a treat.

Cheers big man :)